# Inserting a DECIMAL(10,4) into DECIMAL(10,6) column in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, psql

I'm trying to increase the precision of an already existing table so that new data that is more precise, doesn't get rounded off. I still want to keep the old data around.

I have a table that has a column as follows:

```
rate     NUMERIC(10,4)     not null
```

I'm creating a table that has the column as follows:

```
rate    NUMERIC(10,6)      not null
```

I'm trying to insert the data from the old table into the new column by doing this:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (SELECT * FROM old_table)
```

I get an error as follows:

```
[2023-07-18 10:42:16] [XX000] ERROR: Numeric data overflow (result precision)
[2023-07-18 10:42:16] Detail:
[2023-07-18 10:42:16] -----------------------------------------------
[2023-07-18 10:42:16] error:  Numeric data overflow (result precision)
[2023-07-18 10:42:16] code:      1058
[2023-07-18 10:42:16] context:   64 bit overflow
[2023-07-18 10:42:16] query:     61934434
[2023-07-18 10:42:16] location:  numeric_bound.cpp:112
[2023-07-18 10:42:16] process:   query0_123_61934434 [pid=13888]
[2023-07-18 10:42:16] -----------------------------------------------
```

How can I copy data into the new table from the old table?

Any help is appreciated!

Things I've tried:

I tried CASTING as a NUMERIC(10,6) but it didn't work.
Also tried multiplying by 1.000000 and doing a ROUND, but no luck there either.

Comment: Did you mean to create a `NUMERIC(12, 6)`? A `NUMERIC(10, 6)` can only go up to 10^4-1. Your `NUMERIC(10, 4)` data probably has values greater than that (since it can go up to  10^6-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marth to the rescue!

```
Did you mean to create a NUMERIC(12, 6)? A NUMERIC(10, 6) can only go up to 10^4-1. Your NUMERIC(10, 4) data probably has values greater than that (since it can go up to 10^6-1).
```

Changing the table definition to `NUMERIC(12,6)` worked! I could copy stuff in.